# how to make default index file shown in $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, indexing

Apache uses `index.*` as the default file if a viewer goes to a website with domain name domainname.com and the url in browser will show www.domainname.com.   If we use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`  in linked page from this default page, then we only see the  www.domainname.com but cannot get the real file name of the default page (`index.php`).  Is there a way that we can get referral page filename when it was hidden due to it is a default page?  Or is there any way that we can make default index page shown in the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`  request?

Comment: This server variable is set by the user agent(user's browser) and for that reason it is unreliable because some browsers may not set, or one browser sets it to something different than another as per documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Apache figures out which is the default index file by  "DirectoryIndex  newdefault.php  index.php" in the .htaccess file. How to make apache deliver this info newdefault.php along with the web content to browser?

Comment: Apache won't deliver this info to php, this info is just used so that apache has a default page to direct the user to when you type www.domainname.com without giving a specific page in the url. Futhermore, the http referer request is sent by the client which leaves it up to the client what gets sent to the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable(you have no control of this).  If you are just trying to keep track of which page the user was referred to within the scope of your website than you could store `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in a session variable